# Calling Child component function from Parent component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to call a function in my child component from a button click event in my parent component.

**Parent Component:**

```
class Parent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            //..
        }
    }

    handleSaveDialog = (handleSaveClick) => {
        this.handleSaveClick = handleSaveClick;
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.openDialog}>Open Dialog</Button>
                <Dialog>
                    <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Child Dialog</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <Child handleSaveData={this.handleSaveDialog}/>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleSaveClick} color="primary">
                            Save
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>       
            </div>  
        );
    }
}
```

In the above code, the Parent component renders a Child component modal dialog (based on Material-UI) on click of a button. The Save button, part of the `Dialog` component in Parent, when clicked should call a save function in the `Child` component. As you can see, I have passed a callback function `handleSaveDialog` through the `Child`component props named `handleSaveData`. The save button click will call `handleSaveClick` on the child, once the Child component mounts and passes the callback to the Parent component.

**Child Component:**

```
class Child extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            //..
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('mount');
        this.props.handleSaveData( () => this.handleSaveClick());
    }

    handleSaveClick = () => {
        console.log('save clicked');
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                //..
            </div>      

        );
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am using the accessing the callback function passed by the `Parent` component props and binding it to the `Child` component's save fucntion `handleSaveClick`.

**Problem:**

When I click the Open Dialog button in Parent, for the first time, the `Dialog` mounts the Child component. However, the click on `Save` button does not work (no error). After, closing the dialog, when I reopen the Dialog and click on Save, the `handleSaveClick` in the Child dialog is triggered and a message is logged in the browser console. Any idea why this works on the second time and not the first time?
Remember, the Child Component is mounted/loaded only when I click the Open Dialog on the Parent component.

***References:***

https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#form-dialogs

[Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent/45582558#45582558)

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909#issuecomment-390556015

Comment: Can you put your code somewhere like codesandbox or in stackblitz. Its hard to tell from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not work because if you console log `this.handleSaveClick` in `render` function it will be `undefined` as there is no re-render. So there are 2 ways to go for this:

- Saving function in the state. Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-browser-gw75c

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  openDialog = () => {
    this.setState(preState => ({
      open: !preState.open
    }));
  };

  handleSaveDialog = handleSaveRef => {
    this.setState({
      handleSaveClick: handleSaveRef
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("Render", this.handleSaveClick);
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.openDialog}>Open Dialog</Button>
        <Dialog open={this.state.open}>
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Child Dialog</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <Child handleSaveData={this.handleSaveDialog} />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.state.handleSaveClick} color="primary">
              Save
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

```
class Child extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mount");
    this.props.handleSaveData(this.handleSaveClick);
  }

  handleSaveClick = () => {
    console.log("save clicked");
  };

  render() {
    return <div>//..</div>;
  }
}
```

---

- Using `ref`. Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-kalam-nj29n

```
const childRef = React.createRef();
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  openDialog = () => {
    this.setState(preState => ({
      open: !preState.open
    }));
  };

  handleSaveClick = () => {
    if (childRef.current) {
      childRef.current.handleSaveClick();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.openDialog}>Open Dialog</Button>
        <Dialog open={this.state.open}>
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Child Dialog</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <Child ref={childRef} />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleSaveClick} color="primary">
              Save
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Child extends Component {
  handleSaveClick = () => {
    console.log("save clicked");
  };

  render() {
    return <div>//..</div>;
  }
}
```

---

- Using callback to save instance and than use arrow function:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  openDialog = () => {
    this.setState(preState => ({
      open: !preState.open
    }));
  };

  handleSaveDialog = handleSaveRef => {
    this.handleSaveClick = handleSaveRef;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.openDialog}>Open Dialog</Button>
        <Dialog open={this.state.open}>
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Child Dialog</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <Child handleSaveData={this.handleSaveDialog} />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={() => this.handleSaveClick()} color="primary">
              Save
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mount");
    this.props.handleSaveData(this.handleSaveClick);
  }

  handleSaveClick = () => {
    console.log("save clicked");
  };

  render() {
    return <div>//..</div>;
  }
}
```

You will need to use arrow function in `onClick` as it will create a new function every time we click and thus getting a new instance of `handleClick`. And if you pass `this.handleClick` it won't work because it is `undefined`. You can check this by logging the value of `this.handleClick` in `render` function.

---

**Note:** Use the `2` option its more reliable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just as a warning, you may get downvotes. You should post the code rather than links, as those can go away :)

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know you could use refs like that. Upvoted.

Comment: I don't want to use refs.This looked better to me: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909#issuecomment-390556015

Comment: Have updated the answer to use this method. Check the third point.

Comment: One thing I noticed, the `createRef` is placed outside the class. Why will it not work if placed inside the constructor or somewhere withing the class? Is there any drawbacks of this?

Comment: It will work inside the constructor as well. You can check the docs on refs on react documentation. You can follow that as well.

Comment: Well thought answer. Upvoted =)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know why you have this sort of scenario but the first things that comes in my mind is that you can write `handleSaveClick` method in your Parent component. And in case you need to use that function on any action that might be happening in your child component, you can pass this function as a prop from parent component. So your both cases can be handled

- You can call this method on something happening in parent component
- You can use the same method on any action that is happening in your child component.

If still you think that you have to define the method in your child component, you can use the `refs`

Comment: There are lots of logic implemented while saving the data, including validations. I preferred to keep it within the child component where it makes sense.

Comment: Then as mentioned, you can use `refs` in this particular scenario.